# creating mail form in html and php

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am currently having issues getting my php and html working correctly.  When I click 'submit' It goes to an error page saying it cannot find webpage I requested (www.website.com/contact-form-handler.php).

Here is the PHP and HTML

HTML:

```
<html>  
<head></head
<body>

<div>  
<form action="contact-form-handler.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group">
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="Name" required>
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="Email" required>
                        <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneInput" placeholder="Phone" required>
                        <input name="location" type="text" class="form-control" id="locationInput" placeholder="Event Location" required>
                        <select name="eventType" type="select" class="form-control" id="eventTypeInput">
                          <option selected>Type of Event</option>
                          <option value="1">Business</option>
                          <option value="2">Party</option>
                          <option value="3">Speech</option>
                        </select> 
                        <select name="reference" type="select" class="form-control" id="referenceInput">
                          <option selected>How did you hear about us?</option>
                          <option value="1">Social Media</option>
                          <option value="2">Word of Mouth</option>
                          <option value="3">Google Search</option>
                        </select>         
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group">
                        <textarea name="message" rows="7" class="form-control" id="messageInput" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 font3">
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="form-control" id="submit" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php 
$errors = '';
$emails = 'myemail@myemail.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['phone']) ||
   empty($_POST['location']) ||

{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Please fill out required fields";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$location = $_POST['location']; 
$eventType = $_POST['eventType']; 
$reference = $_POST['reference']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $emails; 
    $subject = "David Does Stuff Inquiry: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Phone: $phone \n Location of event: $location \n Type of Event: $eventType \n How did you hear about us: $reference \n Message \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $email_address\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $emails";

    mail($to,$subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');

} 
?>
```

Comment: try to access the page directly by going to yourdomain.com/contact-form-handler.php and see if it works

Comment: Well the page is not there then   as the error  says

Comment: @Dagon if you cant access the page directly either the page name is incorrect or it isn't in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

See if your PHP file name is "contact-form-handler.php" or maybe you're getting the error coz' your PHP file might not be in the same directory.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your form

```
<form action="contact-form-handler.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
```

your header location is incorrect, it should be

```
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.php');
```